# Can a casual, 'bad' player compete with other casual, 'bad' players around the same skill?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any way or skill system in League of Legends to challenge people around the same skill level?

Basic story:
My friends and I get together for gaming once a week for a couple hours. Normally, this is the only time we play video games due to getting old, having a wife, kids, job etc.  The few times we try to play League of Legends to relive the glory days we are stomped so hard our team k/d ratio is 1/20ish.

Will the system eventually pit us against other players of somewhat similar skill levels as we are just playing un-ranked mode or does skill of players not get calculated in this game?

Comment: That is in theory the whole ***point*** of matchmaking; so the game matches you with players of similar skill. Whether League's works correctly has been up for debate pretty much since the game launched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In every game mode you have a hidden MMR (Matchmaking Rating). It is based on the [Elo System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) but as already said: It's hidden. Now the most accurate this MMR gets is by calculating your Win/Loss ratio. In-game stats may be important but they aren't reliable. A Toplaner with 0/3/0 Can still win a match and be the deciding factor in a lategame teamfight. May it only be because he's behind and getting focussed first instead of the ADC. The system can't really look at your actual skill since there are other factors than a KDA that win a game.

Since you were talking about these "Glory Days" I assume you guys used to be better at league as you are now. If you don't play for a while your real skill will get worse, maybe your League points in ranked may even drop **but your MMR remains the same**. This can be a real problem. I experienced this myself (I didn't play league for a month or so and after that I dropped from plat 1 to plat 5). Basically: **You have to continue to lose until your MMR gets rebalanced**.

The only thing that you could actually try is a Ranked 5v5  or 3v3 Team. In this Queue you have a team MMR instead of single ones for each individual player. The only 2 disadvantages to the team method are: You have to play draft-pick and it can be really frustrating since usually players have much higher soloq ratings than team ratings (Most Gold 5 Teams consist of only Platinum/Diamond Soloqueue Players).

Other than that the only thing you can do is Playing until your MMR reaches your skill level (Be it through getting better yourself or just losing alot)

Comment: The other thing you could try is smurf accounts. Just sayin' :)

Comment: "try...a Ranked 5v5 or 3v3" I must disagree here, I strongly encourage players who are trying to learn or relearn LOL to not play ranked, as it is very difficult on the other players where the game counts for their ranking. If you are trying to relearn LOL, and especially if you have a 1/20 KDA ratio, I would recommend using normals (where people are more relaxed, and the loss/win does not count for each players rank), and not ranked (which should be taken more seriously IMO).

Comment: @Linuxmint Lets face it ranked is a joke unless you are plat or above. I have been in bronze, silver and gold, these kinds of levels mainly have people that don't really care to much. Above these levels is where the game gets a bit more serious. Bronze I have found easier to win then normal games, silver can be a pain but still its not overly that hard. Gold starts getting a bit better but 90% of people rage. I feel ranked is the way to go just to sort out the skill level, it is more controlled compared to normal.

Comment: @Linuxmint which other players will there be who care for the ranking? The opposing team? Your point is valid in solo or duo queue, but we're talking about Ranked Teams. If someone doesn't want his ranking to suffer because of these players, he can just not join the team...

Comment: @scenia I may be mistaken, but I think we were discussing Ranked Solo Que and calling it Ranked 5v5 3v3.

Comment: @Linuxmint I think you are. He's suggesting a 5v5 or 3v3 Team because "In this Queue you have a team MMR instead of single ones for each individual player."

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the answer that **Jutschge** has given but I would like to go a bit more into the solution of the problem you find yourself in.

### Short Answer

You should try to play ranked games as a duo, this system tends to work better overall for player placement and skill level.

---

### A bit more In-Depth

As you are playing normals these tend to be "unreliable" in terms of skill level, I would say I'm a good player and I mainly always have positive K/D in normal games (normally by quite a lot) but I play with a friend and most games this friend has negative K/D. Overall I am I much better player than this friend but I feel as if the system keeps giving us lower skill level opponents than we should be getting. Here is where I think the system does not work, it is hard to tell where a group of 2 should be in a normal game due to the massive skill level differences between the two.

Now moving onto the solution, playing ranked.

Now I know this will seem like ranked is clearly going to be harder and we just want to play for fun, ranked will not provide us with this but I would disagree. Ranked seems to match a lot better with who you should be playing with.

Just a word of warning the first 10 games can be hard and a little stressful as the game is finding out your skill level from these first 10 games. After the first 10 you will be placed in a league tier.

```
Bronze -> Silver -> Gold -> Platinum -> Diamond -> Challenger
```

In each of these (except challenger) have divisions from 1 to 5 (1 being the highest), you will move up and down depending if your winning or losing. (More on this [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_system))

If you play these games with your friend you will be placed with in the same tier and the skill level the game thinks you should be at. Using your team MMR to match you with other players around that. Now the good thing is if you keep losing games it will start dropping you divisions/leagues and you should start noticing a difference in player skill of your opponents.

I would recommend trying this out and see how it does, give it a little bit of time to let the game place you a bit better then just the first 10 ranked games. Feel free to drop back and let us know how it is going.

Hope this helped, please do ask any questions about this if you have any.

Comment: I will give this a try! Thank you, the word 'ranked' always scared me off as a very casual player

Comment: @Quinma I was also like that at one point, I didn't want to go to ranked as I was a casual player. I thought why shouldn't i just give it ago, so I did. Ended up in Silver 3 and to my surprise it was pretty close to my skill level at that time. Ranks to me are no different to normals except more control over players levels. The system doesn't always work but it should sort out overtime if thats the case.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the matchmaking is to play around people your own skill level.

1)  With **glory days**, you make it sound like you guys used to play it a lot.  This likely means your MMR is much higher than your actual current skill.  It is trying to match you against those higher levels.

2)  When you play with 1 or more people, it assumes you have some team synergy and so it will actually boost the MMR of your whole team as another effect.

3) Sometimes higher ranked players rarely play normals.  When they do, their normals MMR is often very low and so it places them vs easier opponents.

Between the first 2 points, you are sort of crippling yourself and the match making sounds like it is working correctly along the rules we were given for it.  As for point 3, that's just bad luck.  It's going to happen and there is nothing you can do about it.

**Solutions?**

1) Create a smurf.  You will quickly get adjusted to your skill level in a shorter number of games, and your first few games might even be a bit easy for you.

2) If you have a full 5, you can create a ranked team for these occasions.

3) Not ideal, but you can simply just continue to play games and losing them.  Eventually your matchmaking will balance out to your current lower skill level.  It just might take a bit of time.

Comment: you are correct, we used to play a lot and used to be much better.  I appreciate the solutions

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, as you play more games, you will get put against players of your own skill level.
The comments above describe how exactly...
However, if try playing against bots. For beginners, it's the perfect matchup!